# CSS. Border outside background

Tags: css, background, styles, border

I have simple problem, but I can't fix It by myself. I have background and can't set border outside It. How to fix It?

Here is my body css:

```
body {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 500px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-width: 100%;
    background-image:url('kalendorius3.png');
    background-size:100% 500px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

This is picture how my border looks like now:

[image: border]

Could you help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `margin:0px; padding:0px` to the body css.

Try this if your looking to center the  border, background image and the content:

```
body {
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px;
} 
#wrapper{
  margin:0px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width:940px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  background:url('kalendorius3.png') no-repeat top;
}
```

The html in the body:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      content goes here....
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, your method worked, but now It looks like: www.eurokos.lt/under20/look.png in right side no border.

Answer (score 0):

first of all

remove

```
border-width: 100%;
```

and that might actually solve your issue

if it doesn't also make sure you add this to body

```
body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, second method worked for me, but now It looks like: www.eurokos.lt/under20/look.png in right side no border.